# Display block a display none element onclick from another component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want that a button clicks the window to be displayed on the screen.

I tried to put the id window into a variable, but its value is null. The first time it worked.

Do I have to use props? How? Or where to put the window variable?

The project's GitHub link:
https://github.com/folza1/react-modulzaro-question

```
import "./App.css";

const window = document.getElementById("window");
console.log(window);
window.style.display = "none";

function Window() {
  return (
    <>
      <div id="window"></div>
    </>
  );
}

function Div() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="divStyle">
        <button
          id="button"
          onClick={function () {
            window.style.display = "block";
          }}
        >
          DETAILS
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <div id="main">
        <Div />
        <Window />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
```

also you can handle it with useState:
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

into return Div components :

```
       <button 
           onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)} >
           Toggle 
      </button>
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <div id="main">
        <Div />
        <Window />
      {toggle && (
         <Window />
      )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I need not toggle, only display. The display none will be if I click on the window.

Comment: You set a boolean value in the state  and then do:

```var style = {};
if (!state) {
  style.display = 'block'
}```

```return <div style={style}>...</div>```

Comment: Exactly not clear how you say. Could you send a full solution with the example? There are 3 components. Where to put the state?